# Call to Execute Method Returns Null in Normal Code Execution But Returns Data When Stepped Through

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm trying to call an API using the RestSharp library. Running the code normally fails to fetch the data but when I step through the code while debugging, the ***Execute*** method fetches the data.

```
//execute the request
var response = client.Execute<JimiResponse<List<DeviceTrackListResponse>>>(webRequest);
```

```
private List<DeviceTrackListResponse> GetDeviceTrackListData(string accessToken, string imei, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var client = new RestClient(_security.EndPoint);
    var webRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    var requiredParams = new DeviceTrackListRequest(accessToken)
    {
        app_key = _security.AppKey,
        imei = imei,
        method = "jimi.device.track.list",
        begin_time = startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
        end_time = endDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    };

    webRequest.AddObject(requiredParams);

    try
    {
        var signature = Signature.SignTopRequest(requiredParams.GetProperties(), _security.SecurityToken, requiredParams.sign_method);
        webRequest.AddParameter("sign", signature);

        //execute the request
        var response = client.Execute<JimiResponse<List<DeviceTrackListResponse>>>(webRequest);

        var responseData = response?.Data?.Result;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && responseData != null)
        {
            return responseData;
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<DeviceTrackListResponse>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new List<DeviceTrackListResponse>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not running this code async, it will not wait for the response and continue to run after it hits that line.

```
 private async Task<List<DeviceTrackListResponse>> GetDeviceTrackListData(string accessToken, string imei, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var client = new RestClient(_security.EndPoint);
    var webRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    var requiredParams = new DeviceTrackListRequest(accessToken)
    {
        app_key = _security.AppKey,
        imei = imei,
        method = "jimi.device.track.list",
        begin_time = startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
        end_time = endDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    };

    webRequest.AddObject(requiredParams);

    try
    {
        var signature = Signature.SignTopRequest(requiredParams.GetProperties(), _security.SecurityToken, requiredParams.sign_method);
        webRequest.AddParameter("sign", signature);

        //execute the request
        var response = await client.Execute<JimiResponse<List<DeviceTrackListResponse>>>(webRequest);

        var responseData = response?.Data;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && responseData != null)
        {
            return responseData;
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<DeviceTrackListResponse>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new List<DeviceTrackListResponse>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it `async` but it still does not return data when I run normally. But when I step through, it does.